# How do you calculate the line of shortest distance between two sets of line segments that passes through a known point?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given two sets of line segments (xa1..N,ya1..N) and (xb1..N,yb1..N) that represent the upper and lower surfaces of a geology unit, and a known point (xc1,yc1) within the geology unit, how do I find the line of shortest distance between (xa,ya) and (xb,yb) that passes through (xc1,yc1).

Comment: Is this really a Fortran question? Or is it a math/algorithm question?

Comment: Geology unit is just a layer of rock, so in 2D the two sets of line segements do not meet.

Comment: Yes it is a math/algo question but 1st time on stackoverflow so did not know how to use the tag bit. I program in fortran so just chose that.

Comment: I require the answer so that I can work out where the internal point sits relative to the upper and lower surfaces. If the geology unit is folded I can the work out how to unfold retaining the spatial relationships

Comment: More clarification is needed since it isn't clear that there is a solution.  How do you know there are points in each of the sets colinear with (xc1, and yc1)?  Given that the data is taken as a measurement, the probability that a solution exists is near 0.

Comment: You need to clarify: 1) does your two sets of segments are polylines (ie the end of a segment is the beginning of the next)? 2) Does the line of shortest distance need to be straight or can it be split in two non-colinear segments joined at (xc1,yc1)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are looking for an intermediate polyline between two given polylines, through a given point.

If your two source polylines have the same point count, you can consider linear interpolation between corresponding segments, using a parameter t in range [0 1]. Every new vertex is given by

```
Xti = (1 - t) Xai + t Xbi
Yti = (1 - t) Yai + t Ybi
```

When t=0, this gives the upper surface, t=1 the lower surface and other t intermediate surfaces.

Now remains to find the t value that makes the line pass through (xc, yc). Every segment can be represented by its parametric equation, between point i and i+1 (let j), using some parameter p. This leads to the following equations:

```
Xc= (1 - p) Xti + p Xtj
Yc= (1 - p) Yti + p Ytj
```

Now, for every i-j segment, you have a system of two equations in two unknowns (t and p). You will keep the i-j solution such that p falls in range [0 1]